# Get slot data as a variable in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, prismjs, vuejs-slots

I have a component (`prism-editor`) that only takes code from `v-model="code"`. This means, the code has to be sent to the component through `code`:

#### Code.vue

```
<template>
  <prism-editor class="my-editor" v-model="code" 
    :highlight="highlighter" :line-numbers="numbers"/>
</template>

<script>  
  import { PrismEditor } from 'vue-prism-editor';

  export default {
    components: {
      PrismEditor,
    },
    data: () => ({
        code: this.$slots,
        numbers: true
    }),
  }
</script>
```

I would like to bind this from a parent component named `Code` from a slot:

#### Page.vue

```
<template>
    <code language="c">
        int main() {
            printf('Hello World!');
        }
    </code>
<template>

<script>
  import Code from 'code.vue'
  export default {
    components: {
      'code': Code
    }
  }
</script>
```

In my `Code` component, I have to find a way to get and pass the slot data directly to the `code` variable to be sent to the `v-model='code'`. Unfortunately the following doesn't work because I don't know how to get the data from the parent `slot`:

```
data: () => ({
    code: this.$slots // Which obviously doesn't work...
})
```

Said differently, I just want to get all the raw content that was sent inside the `code` tag:

```
<code>all this content...</code>`
```

Is this possible?

```
.
├── Code.vue
└── Page.vue
```

Comment: please explain more about the components structure

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have edited my question, I don't know what information do you need.

Comment: i mean which is the parent and child component and how they're structured

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I've added more information, I hope it helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question, in order to solve that you would have to go a layer below Vuejs, and use the property `textContent` from the DOM API [[read more here]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

With this property you can access the content inside of a DOM element, so in your case it would be something like:

```
/*
 * Template
 */
<div ref="mySlot">
  <slot></slot>
</div>

/*
 * Javascript
 */
this.$refs.mySlot.textContent;
```

I've setup a nice example for you in Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-resonance-7unn2?file=/src/components/Code.vue

For future challenges:

Always try to see if you can solve it with pure Javascript. Happy coding mate;

Comment: Do there is no `Vue` wrapper to get this information without hacking the `$refs`?

Comment: In which way, using $refs is a hack?

Either way, you can use other alternatives to access the element, use one that suits your application best.

Comment: @nowox, `$refs` is exactly that: Vue's wrapper to interact with template entities, whether they're DOM elements or child components (vue instances). It's the exact opposite of a hack. And its only purpose is to allow you (the developer) to interact with the template without hacking. If this need did not exist, `$refs` wouldn't have been added to Vue.