# Vue: Read/Write all data inside a slot as one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to build a vue component that will e.g. have a button to reset all state inside its slot. To have a "minimal" example, I have here removed styling, extra functionality etc.

E.g. my-reseter-component:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <slot></slot>
   <v-btn @click="dialog_action_reset()">
  <div>
<template>
<script>  
export default {
  data() { 
    return{ init_state:NaN}
  },
  created:{
    this.init_state=???????? // javascript code to copy data of slot
  },  
  methods: {
    dialog_action_reset() {
      //javascript code to restore from this.init_state
      ????????????
    }
  }
```

I could then use this as e.g.:

How would I access(read restore) the data inside the slot?

Alternatively, if I am going about this wrong, what would be a valid approach/architecture
that would allow me to implement this functionality without having to list all data inside the set of components to be reset?

[get-slot-data-as-a-variable-in-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63426511/get-slot-data-as-a-variable-in-vue) seems to have much similarity to the reading part of my question, but the solution proposed seems to be specific to the question's part about the specific component(?)

To read, I have tried a lot, including:

```
            var slot_data = this.$slots['default'][0];
            var slot_data2 =Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(slot_data,"componentInstance")
```

The second line does not work and returns undefined, although in firefoxe's console I can see a property(?) componentInstance that contains my data...(wonder why?)

Answer (score 2):

The elements that go into your component slot are effectively coded in the parent, so why don't you just `$emit` a signal after the button is pressed? This way you don't have to pass any data into the resetter component:

```
    dialog_action_reset() {
      this.$emit('reset-slot')
    }
```

Then you listen on this signal in the parent component, and trigger the data reset:

```
<template>
  <resetter @reset-slot="resetData">
    <div>Foo</div>
  </resetter>
</template>
<script>  
export default {
  data() { 
    return{ some_state: 0 }
  },  
  methods: {
    resetData() {
       this.some_state = 0
    }
  }
```